# Regex to extract specific text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following HTML string that I'm trying to extract specific text.  `(BASEBALL, FOOTBALL)`

I've tried certain regexs but I can only get the first match or I can use look behind but that is not supported by mobile safari.  Any better ways?

This text will ALWAYS be preceeded by  `style='font-weight:bold;'>` and can be used to determine this text without any other issues.

```
<div><span class="label"> <b>19:43:08 pm</b></span> <strong><span style="cursor:pointer;">Gello:</span></strong> <span><strong>These are my favorite sports -- <div><button  class='btn' type='button'  style='font-weight:bold;'>BASEBALL</span></button></div> gets <div class='dropdown' style='display:inline-block;'><button  class='btn' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' style='font-weight:bold;'>FOOTBALL</span></button></div> oijd;osijf osidj osd jfsoij fosj f.</strong></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group with a lazy match in your regex.

```js
const rx = /style='font-weight:bold;'>(.*?)<\/span>/g

const found = []
let m = rx.exec(input)
while (m) {
 found.push(m[1])
 let m = rx.match(input)
}
```

If you have false positives, you might want to limit the characters in the group.  In this case, you do not even have to match the end tag following your text.

```js
const rx = /style='font-weight:bold;'>([A-Z]+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style=(?:'|")font-weight:bold;(?:'|")>(\w+)
```

This regex will detect ' or ", but you still need to delete `style` to `>` to get the `BASEBALL` and `FOOTBALL`